# Why does adding <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" /> to web config give a server error?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure

I'm trying to fix the common error "A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (*)" by allowing the * character.  In [Scott H's post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ExperimentsInWackinessAllowingPercentsAnglebracketsAndOtherNaughtyThingsInTheASPNETIISRequestURL.aspx) he recommends adding the following to the web.config

```
<system.web>
 <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
```

When I do this I get a "The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.".

- I've double checked I have .NET 2.0 installed
- No errors are caught in global.asax
- We are using the azure emulator
- We're using a mvc 4.5 app

Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: My guess is your code is throwing an exception. Log the exception and see what it is. [Elmah](http://www.nuget.org/packages/elmah/) makes this easy in Asp.Net MVC.

Comment: @Nathan The error being generated never hits the global or elmah

Comment: did you check the Application Event Log in windows?

Comment: Looks like a configuration error. Is this the only `httpRuntime` entry in web.config?

Comment: @Andrei  I think that was it, if you add as answer I'll give you credit.  Thanks!

Comment: Please provide bigger sample from your web.config, along with exact exception and stacktrace!